# Building android-maven project in netbeans

Tags: java, android, maven, netbeans

I am trying to get up and running a new android-maven project in Netbeans 7.1.1. I keep getting this error

> Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.1.1:dex (default-dex) on project myproject: MojoExecutionException: ANDROID-040-001: Could not execute: Command = cmd.exe /X /C ""C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_03\jre\bin\java" -Xmx1024M -jar "C:\Program Files\Android\android-sdk\platform-tools\lib\dx.jar" --dex "--output=C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\target\classes.dex" "C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\My Documents\NetBeansProjects\MyProject\target\classes"", Result = 1 -> [Help 1]

This is the pom file: http://pastebin.com/k1ZzfEYY

Comment: try running maven goal with `-e` flag and grab the cause of the error

Comment: `-e` flag on http://pastebin.com/5BtfPnP5

Comment: For everyone else who will hit this wall, my problem was that I was using java 1.7. Downgraded to 1.6 and problems are gone.
From what I have read, using 1.7 for android development is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

No. You don't have to downgrade to a Java 6 SDK from Java 7 SDK to use Maven with Android.

The problem is that after you made some updates with the SDK Manager something got corrupted and you no longer have the dx.jar file in your **android-sdk\platform-tools\lib** folder, and when you try to build with Maven your project doesn't have that jar in the path and it fails to build.

To fix this you need to open the SDK Manager and delete the "***Android SDK Platform-tools***" that you currently have installed and reinstall it. After that go to the android-sdk\platform-tools\lib folder and see if the dx.jar file is there and try to build your project with **mvn clean install android:deploy**.

I've tested this with the sample [helloflashlight](https://github.com/jayway/maven-android-plugin-samples/tree/master/helloflashlight) application and it worked correctly after I've reinstalled the platform tools.

Also make sure that you have the environment variables JAVA_HOME, ANDROID_HOME, M2_HOME pointing to the right paths.